# Remote Maven library can be added, but import statement fails

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I've created a library, published it to an S3 Maven repository, and successfully added it to a new Android Studio 3.5.3 app project by adding the Maven location in the project's build.gradle file and including

```
implementation 'com.mydomain:my_library:1.0.0'
```

in the module's build.gradle file. (Gradle sync completes without errors.)

However, when I go to use the library in a Java file in the new app project with:

```
import com.mydomain.my_library.*;
```

it immediately gives an error "cannot resolve symbol 'mydomain'".

Notes:

- When I type "import com." it shows me options to import my library's dependency packages, just not my library itself.
- The library is part of a regular app project and the above import statement works fine in that app.
- I looked in .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1 folder and see the com.mydomain/my_library/1.0.0 folder, but that folder only contains (a randomly generated folder that contains) the POM file. There is no AAR file, which I think is the real problem. Both the my_library-1.0.0.aar and my_library-1.0.0.pom files are in the repository. I'm using Gradle 5.4.1 and Gradle Plugin 3.5.3.
- When I add "@aar" to the dependency line (implementation 'com.mydomain:my_library:1.0.0@aar'), it downloads the AAR file and the import line works, but the library's dependencies are not downloaded. Now I'd like to know how to make "@aar" not a requirement for users of my library. Hint: it's impossible. See answer below.

Here is the beginning of the library's POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_library</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>androidx.appcompat</groupId>
        <artifactId>appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
    ...
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that in AS but try to clean caches, for example in the Intellij you ca try `file` -> `Invalidate caches / restart`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that with no luck. I even tried creating a new app project from scratch and tried to add my library with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I finally got it through my head that if you publish an AAR library (because it contains resources like layouts and images), your library's users must use "@aar" in their dependency. And if your AAR library has dependencies, your library's users must use {transitive = true} in their dependency.

```
implementation ('com.mydomain:my_library:1.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

In other words, if your users don't specify "@aar", Gradle won't download your .aar file. If they do specify "@aar", Gradle won't download your library's dependencies unless they also use the transitive parameter.

Don't really understand why Gradle doesn't work the same way with aar Maven packaging as it does with jar packaging, but I can now move on...